# Simple Python Socket Server Not Taking Conditional Statement

Tags: python, sockets

I attempted to find an answer for this, but most examples out there are for purely echo base Socket Servers.

Basically I have the following code:

```
import socket
import sys
from thread import *

HOST = ''   # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 8888 # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

#Bind socket to local host and port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

#Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'

#Function for handling connections. This will be used to create threads
def clientthread(conn):
    #Sending message to connected client
    conn.send('Welcome to the server. Type something and hit enter\n') #send only takes string

    #infinite loop so that function do not terminate and thread do not end.
    while True:

        #Receiving from client
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if data == "hello":
                reply = 'OK...Hello back to you'
        else:
                reply = '01:OK - ' + data
        if not data:
            break

        conn.sendall(reply)

    #came out of loop
    conn.close()

#now keep talking with the client
while 1:
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])

    #start new thread takes 1st argument as a function name to be run, second is the tuple of arguments to the function.
    start_new_thread(clientthread ,(conn,))

s.close()
```

Everything works great until I try to use a conditional statement. I am very new to python and I am using this as a way to learn it a little better, but when the following line runs it skips the `if` each time.

```
#Receiving from client
data = conn.recv(1024)
if data == "hello":
     reply = 'Why hello there!'
else:
     reply = '01:OK - ' + data
if not data:
     break

conn.sendall(reply)
```

From the telnet client I am connecting to it just echos everything I send it including the `'hello'` I send it rather than the phrase.

I have a feeling that it is something simple, but I am not sure the format of the `data` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close!

Telnet will send whatever EOL delimiter you gave it, along with the text.  So if you type "data" and press enter, `data` is actually something like `hello\r\n`.

You can effectively ignore this whitespace by doing something like changing

```
data = conn.recv(1024)
```

to

```
data = conn.recv(1024).strip()
```

And you should be good to go.

EDIT:

As noted in the comments, the network may split up the message into multiple packets.  To work around this, you can use use the [`socket.makefile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile) method and get a file-like object and then use `readline()` which will block until a complete line is available. For example, changing `clientthread` to:

```
def clientthread(conn):
    #Sending message to connected client
    conn.send('Welcome to the server. Type something and hit enter\n') #send only takes string

    sfh = conn.makefile("r+b", bufsize=0)

    #infinite loop so that function do not terminate and thread do not end.
    while True:

        #Receiving from client
        data = sfh.readline().strip()
        if data == "hello":
                reply = 'OK...Hello back to you'
        else:
                reply = '01:OK - ' + data
        if not data:
            break

        conn.sendall(reply)

    #came out of loop
    conn.close()
```

```
== PYTHON ==
Socket created
Socket bind complete
Socket now listening
Connected with 192.168.1.10:42749

== TELNET ==
$ telnet 192.168.1.106 8888
Trying 192.168.1.106...
Connected to 192.168.1.106.
Escape character is '^]'.
Welcome to the server. Type something and hit enter
hello
OK...Hello back to you
```

Comment: data will _usually_ be hello\r\n, but it can also be h, he, hel, hell, hello, hello\r or hello\r\n.  This trips a lot of beginning socket programmers, and leads to bugs that only show up with high network load or long network paths.  To get around this, consider something like http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/bufsock.html  HTH

Comment: This is perfect, thanks guys! I knew it had to be fairly simple.